# Consolidating 2 excel files - function consolidate

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having trouble with consolidating data from 2 excel files...

file1.xlsx

[image]

file2.xlsx

[image]

i would like to get something like this....

[image]

How would I do this with consolidating function. I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b) but it doesn't seem to update.

Comment: What tutorial? What consolidation function?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is merge data from different files, not consolidate data from different sheets. The Consolidate command from the ribbon will always aggregate the numeric data, not just slot it in.

There is no built-in easy one-click feature that does what you describe. Here is a possible approach for manual merging:

Copy the "New" column from one file and paste it next to the existing "New" column in the other file. Then use a formula in the next column, like

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D2),D2,IF(ISNUMBER(E2),E2,""))
```

Copy the formula all the way down and the sheet looks like this:

[image]

Now copy the data from column F to column D and delete columns E and F.

Comment: great!!!!! now once when column F is done...Can I quickly grab column D and E and delete it? No because column F is formula and therefore depends on these columns. Is there way to quickly get rid of DE and keep column F which in turn will become column D if I remove DE

Comment: Read the last sentence below the screenshot. Paste as values, then you won't lose anything.

Comment: I know that. I was just hoping I could do quick delete

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Microsoft Add-In Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) in order to merge several files together. Combining data from multiple data sources is a core functionality of Power Query. More on the MS Website [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-data-from-multiple-data-sources-Power-Query-70cfe661-5a2a-4d9d-a4fe-586cc7878c7d).

In your example I make the assumption that you have in the first three columns identical values and that in the "new" one you have only in one of the two files a value.

You have two queries in Power Query. Here the M code, which you can use.

Read the file2 in a first query (only as connection):

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\tmp\example\file2.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Define Header" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet),
    #"Change Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Define Header",{{"First", type text}, {"Last", type text}, {"Old", Int64.Type}, {"New", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Change Type"
```

Read the file1 and merge it with the first query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\tmp\example\file1.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Define Header" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet),
    #"Change Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Define Header",{{"First", type text}, {"Last", type text}, {"Old", Int64.Type}, {"New", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merge tables" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Change Type",{"First", "Last", "Old"},File2,{"First", "Last", "Old"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expand new column" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merge tables", "NewColumn", {"New"}, {"NewColumn.New"}),
    #"Merge columns ""New""" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expand new column", {{"New", type text}, {"NewColumn.New", type text}}, "de-CH"),{"New", "NewColumn.New"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"New merged")
in
    #"Merge columns ""New"""
```

the output look like this:
[image]